# Maven archetype for creating Vaadin widget

Tags: maven, vaadin, maven-archetype

I'm geting starting with vaadin. I want to create a widget using the source code of a addon, just now I develop with maven, so I need to know how use vaadin-archetype-widget, please I need some documentation about that. Thanks, sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the "vaadin-archetype-widget" you can create and package widgets for use in other projects.

You can use the maven goal "package" which produces a JAR that you can add as a dependency to another Vaadin Maven project.

[Here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/clientside/clientside-widget.html) you can read up how to create your own custom widget.

Comment: Ok, but if I want test my widget, do I have to package the proyect and later add it as a dependency to another proyect? Is there any way to test the widget? This archetype create two modules: one for the widget and other for a demo, it is my doubt, how can use these modules. Cheers

Comment: That's right, you can package it and add it as a dependency! You can test your widget project like all other vaadin projects, just build & deploy it. Follow these instructions [here‌](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Component+Add-on+Project+Setup+HOWTO)​.
`Test that the project compiles and runs by running (Run -> Run as ... -> Maven Build...) maven goal "package jetty:run". If everything compiles fine and Jetty server starts, you can access the application at http://localhost:8080/mylist/`
The guide may be outdated but the approach is still the same

Comment: Thanks, I used the maven goal package, now the archetype creates two modules, one for the widget and other for test the widget, in order to try the widget must be package the module two and deploy it on a server, I deployed the project on Tomcat server and worked well  Thanks.